# Prevent file corruption on exiting node in middle of fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading and writing some txt/json files in Node.js that have become >25mb in file size. If the process is interrupted half way through an fs.writeFile I get an empty file. So basically, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a quick way to prevent file writes from being corrupted if the process is exited. Is there a way to catch the exit and wait until the fs.writeFile callback is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common approach is to first write to a different file (e.g., instead of overwriting *permanent-file.txt* directly, write to *temporary-file.txt*), and then in the callback from `fs.writeFile`, use `fs.rename` to replace the permanent file with the temporary one (e.g., `fs.rename('temporary-file.txt', 'permanent-file.txt');`).

Comment: P.S. If you don't want to roll your own function, there are [several packages that appear to support this already](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=write%20file%20atomic).

Comment: Thanks. The cool thing is that it's all JSON data that I need to bring back into the app, so even a bulk read of all of the files, then a _.flatten would do the trick. Thanks for the advice.